# Is there similar function in Power BI for Excel conditional formatting?

Tags: powerbi

I'm setting up a Power BI report, and want to include conditional formatting. How do I make it possible the conditional formatting in Power BI? (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdn23l1lkcdi5c3/excel_kpi_marks.PNG?dl=0)?

I tried to use the DAX queries. But I can't get the unicode of the symbols as shown in the above figure.

OneMonthwizIcon = IF ( 'data'[One Month] > 10, UNICHAR ( 128316 ), UNICHAR ( 128315 ) ) & data[One Month]

I expect the output to be shown with different icons with the following conditions.
- Less than -10 Down arrow
- Between -10 and 10 Rectange
- Greater than 10 Up arrow

https://www.dropbox.com/s/elroau3n5iq5p1p/excel_kpi_with_data.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to write a dax query for achieving the conditional formatting. The feature is already included on the PowerBI July 2019 update. So it is no more problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table using 'enter data' with the first column corresponding to an output result of your if statement and the URL column which is a URL to the KPI image you want displayed. (Your dropbox link will work).

[image]

Change the Icon column datatype to Image URL:

[image]

Then change your measure to output the corresponding number that matches the symbol you want to see for each condition:

```
OneMonthwizIcon = IF ( 'data'[One Month] > 10, 1, 2 ) & data[One Month]
```

Then if you create a relationship between OneMonthwizIcon and the 'Condition' column which will match on the condition number. Then you can use the Icon column in your table or on the page and you will be able to see the image.